# Read and write a string in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, spim

I'm trying to write a code which simply reads a string prints that string on screen.
Here is the code I have written :

```
    .text
main : 
    la $a0, string_space
    li $a1, 1024
    li $v0, 8
    syscall


    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    li $v0, 10
    syscall





    .data
string_space : .space 1024
```

I get this error : 
**spim: (parser) Label is defined for the second time on line 2 of file code.s
      main : 
           ^**
How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Woks fine here. Make sure you are not linking/appending to other file that already has `main` defined.

Comment: @Jester that was the mistake. Thank you!